# accessing plists on iphone simulator

Tags: iphone, objective-c, plist

So I have started building plist files using NSCoder, but as I"m developing i want to look at them and see what data is being saved.

How do i find/access the plist files generated by my app in the simulator (and on the device when i get to that)

Places Ive looked:

- application bundle
- build directory

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To put them into the ~/Library/Application Support/iPhone Simulator/User/Applications/ subfolder (where they would end up if they were on a real device), you could use the following piece of code in your application:

```
+ (NSString *)dataFilePath:(NSString *)filename {
NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];

return [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:filename];
}
```

This will put the file in the /Documents/ folder of your application's sandbox.
You can then find the file back at: ~/Library/Application Support/iPhone Simulator/User/Applications/ ***Application GUID*** /Documents/

Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

wow that is dumb,

found them at /

this simulator must not emulate the real phone environment well at all.

Answer (score 0):

If your plist is in the Document folder then give the path as

```
NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
```

else if your plist file is in the resource folder then give the path of resource folder as

```
[[NSBundle mainbundle] pathforresources:..........];
```